# VueJS prevent reactive behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can I use [VueDraggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) to clone an item that once cloned has no link to the original item.

Please take this fiddle as an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/32f7yu7c/69/

When you drag an item from list 1 to list 2, please hit the 'update' text and you'll see both names in both lists are updated. How can i prevent this behaviour?

What I would like is this click handler `<span @click="update(index)">Update</span>` is triggered you update only the item in the relative list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, VueDraggable doesn't actually make a deep clone.  You need to add a 'clone' property to your draggable component, with the name of your clone method:

```
<draggable :list="list" class="dragArea" :clone="clone" :options="{group:{ name:'people',  pull:'clone', put:false }}">
```

and add the clone method to your component:

```
clone: function(me) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(me));
}
```

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/3gcyemft/1/

Comment: I literally love you. Thanks!

Comment: Best reaction I've ever gotten :-).  You're welcome.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do we have to do this?

Comment: It's the safe choice.  Some use cases may not want to make copies automatically.